# Code not able to find element using xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

In the example link below I want to use Python Selenium to click the location button so I can extract the post code.

[Link](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.4673404,-2.1656628,3a,75y,358.61h,87.57t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sATiO7xuwJrjpD4R5eBf61w!2e0!7i16384!8i8192)

To find and click this button I am using the below line of code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="widget-titlecard-spotlightcontainer noprint"]').click()
```

I have checked the xpath syntax using the handy chrome add-on and it finds my element, however python doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As I am new to Python and selenium scraping I was not aware I needed to switch the active tab in the script. I thought that because the Chrome window was displaying the tab, it was active but it is not.